# Checking if an attribute value is null or empty

Tags: php, json, rightnow-crm

I am having issue in manipulating JSON data using PHP in Oracle RightNow CRM. The sample json is included below. When I try to check in an if condition, the data contained in the "person.private_email" attribute, it only evaluates to true when there is some data. If there is no data for that attribute, it does nothing. I am not getting any error at all.
What would be the best way to check if any attribute contains no data.

### JSON

```
{
    "PERSON.PERSON_ID": 272839,
    "PERSON.Surname": "FirstName",
    "PERSON.Given_Names": "LastName",
    "PERSON.TITLE": "MR",
    "PERSON.BIRTH_DT": "10/JUL/14",
    "PERSON.GENDER": "M",
    "PERSON.CDU_EMAIL": "S272839@mydomain.com",
    "PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL": ""
}
```

### PHP

```
self::$person=json_decode($json);

if (isset(self::$person->{'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL'}) && !empty(self::$person->{'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL'}))
```

Comment: [**It Works...(Eval.in) ?**](https://eval.in/171283)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether it is null or not, [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is enough, for checking whether it is empty or not, you better [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the string as it removes spaces and spaces are counted as character if you check emptiness with [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.

```
$email = self::$person->{'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL'};
if (isset($email) && trim($email) != '')
    echo "Contains data";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot combine both checking (&&) because isset() will check if PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL is set in JSON data, otherwise if it just blank, then empty() will suffice.

maybe should break it down to something like this:

```
$email = "";

if (isset(self::$person->{'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL'}))
{
   if(!empty(self::$person->{'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL'}))
   {
       $email = self::$person->{'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL'};
   }
else
{
   //email is not set in the json data
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a property exists in an object you can use [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/property_exists):

```
if (property_exists(self::$person, 'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL')) {
    // property exists
    $value = self::$person->{'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL'};
}
```

Note that this will yield `true` even if the property is `null`. To check whether a property exists *and* that it's not `null` you use `isset()`:

```
if (isset(self::$person->{'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL'})) {
    // property exists and is not null
}
```

To check whether something is empty, it's best to define what empty means; if the properties can only be strings, the empty definition could be something like:

```
if (strlen(trim($value))) {
    // string contains at least on non-space
}
```

Comment: hi @jack, property exists always returns true. it doesn't like strlen(trim(self::$person->{'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL'})) :(. still the same issue

Comment: @BishnuPaudel What do you mean by "doesn't like"? And it returns true because the property ... always exists :)

Comment: I mean I am still having the original issue as described in the question. Yes, the property exists . I was just confirming that.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel I think you didn't share enough of your code to really know what's going on. The condition you have in your question is technically a valid way to check whether the value is non-empty ... if you wanted to check for empty values you should reverse the condition of course.

Comment: I think the issue is more specific to my environment. I am using it in Oracle RigtNow CX sytem. Thank you for your inputs. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, you are parsing the json string into a local $person variable, while in your conditionals you are checking a static class property of $person....

ie, $person is not the same as self::$person.  Unless there is more code that you are not sharing, this might be your problem.

This code works for me in RightNow CX w/ CP2.

```
    $json = '{
        "PERSON.PERSON_ID": 272839,
        "PERSON.Surname": "FirstName",
        "PERSON.Given_Names": "LastName",
        "PERSON.TITLE": "MR",
        "PERSON.BIRTH_DT": "10/JUL/14",
        "PERSON.GENDER": "M",
        "PERSON.CDU_EMAIL": "S272839@mydomain.com",
        "PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL": ""
    }';

    $person=json_decode($json);

    if(!empty($person->{'PERSON.PRIVATE_EMAIL'}))
    {
        echo "Not Empty";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "IS Empty";
    }
```